# Can I dispatch root actions from feature store in ngrx?

Tags: ngrx

I'm new to ngrx. I'm little confused in dispatching actions.

State:

```
{
    uiState: UIState,
    featureState: FeatureState
}
```

From my feature effects, I need to dispatch a UI action. So I injected `Store<State>` and dispatch. It worked fine.

But, if I use `Store<featureState>` and dispatch UI action, this also works fine.

I thought, if I dispatch a UI action from feature store, the store will not know which reducer to call for that action and get a default state. But the value in the `uistate` is updated.

So, does this mean I can dispatch any action from anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you can dispatch any action from anywhere.